# Download external file in background PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, curl, background-process

I have three weeks looking for this:

I have this page which have to download a file after verifying the data given by the user. I do the validation and execute an external script which gives me an URL. And I use that URL to download another file which I'm gonna execute later.

I'd tried to download the file with curl, wget, file_put_content, javascript, ajax and jquery with no luck, the file is 150MB+ so I created  a nice progress bar to tell the user how the download is going and already have a method to read the downloaded size.

I fact I'm able to download the file with cURL, but the problem is that the `"do_form.php"` won't load until the file is completely downloaded, so I want to load the page first, then download the file - in the background -, so I can show the user the progress of the download.

Please tell me that this is possible... Thanks!!

Comment: So what was your workaround? I'm looking to do the same thing.

Comment: Today, when I get home I will look for the code and post it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Gearman](http://gearman.org/). Maybe a gearman background job fits your needs. This job can even run on the same machine as the web server. Of course the early response to the page has the disadvantage that it contains no success information. You will need to poll for that information using AJAX again.

If you decide to do so, you should also have a look at [GearmanManager](https://github.com/brianlmoon/GearmanManager) as this eases things a lot.

Comment: Gearman is great, you might also want to consider beanstalkd, great tool that's very simple to use with PHP.

Comment: Thank you guys, I checked both solutions, but my boss doesn't want to install any extra software. So I still looking for an answer... (I think I have a workaround, but I need to test it first, so any answer o comment is welcome)